# mysql grant permissions on all but system tables

Tags: mysql, database, sql-grant, filtered

I am trying to grant a set of permissions to " all databases all tables" *.* excepted mysql system databases (mysql,information_schema,performance_schema, and sys (I believed I named them all?)).

I am not sure how to do that.

I need for instance a GRANT SELECT ON *.* excepted system tables.

Comment: refer to [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98949/grant-select-on-all-databases-except-one-mysql).

Comment: thank you, but the accepted solution doesn't make much sense to me:
SELECT CONCAT("GRANT SELECT ON ",SCHEMA_NAME,".* TO 'test_user'@'localhost';")
FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA 
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME NOT LIKE 'mysql';

SCHEMATA? this has to be a typo?

Comment: no, that's not a typo. That's a proper table. Have you checked information_schema database? You will find that table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

`SELECT CONCAT("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ",SCHEMA_NAME,".* TO 'test_user'@'localhost';") FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema',
'performance_schema','sys')`

This will provide you queries for individual databases that you can use to grant the privileges to a particular user.

After that, use:

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

I hope this helps!